# Retrieving Data From Multiple tables where the second table has a count function with it

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, join, linq-to-sql

[image]

[image]

I have two tables  called  as test_package & Test_info. Test_info table has foreign key relation with test_package with the column name associated_package. i want to retrieve the how many test a package contains with it.....
Output of the query should look like the following figure.....

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?   Instead of a screen shot, show the actual columns you'd like to see in the final result.   You mention wanting to know how many tests a package contain, but your output example doesn't show this number anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Package_id, COUNT(Test_id) FROM test_Package tp
INNER JOIN Test_info ti ON ti.associatedPackage = tp.Package_id
GROUP BY Package_id
```